# Find all k-size subsets with sum s of an n-size bag of duplicate unsorted positive integers

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net-2.0, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Please note that this is required for a **C# .NET 2.0** project (**Linq not allowed**).

I know very similar questions have been asked here and I have already produce some working code (see below) but still would like an advice as to how to make the algorithm faster given k and s conditions.

This is what I've learnt so far:
Dynamic programming is the most efficient way to finding ONE (not all) subsets. Please correct me if I am wrong. And is there a way of repeatedly calling the DP code to produce newer subsets till the bag (set with duplicates) is exhausted?

If not, then is there a way that may speed up the backtracking recursive algorithm I have below which does produce what I need but runs in O(2^n), I think, by taking s and k into account?

Here is my fixed bag of numbers that will NEVER change with n=114 and number range from 3 to 286:

```
    int[] numbers = new int[]
    {
        7, 286, 200, 176, 120, 165, 206, 75, 129, 109,
        123, 111, 43, 52, 99, 128, 111, 110, 98, 135,
        112, 78, 118, 64, 77, 227, 93, 88, 69, 60,
        34, 30, 73, 54, 45, 83, 182, 88, 75, 85,
        54, 53, 89, 59, 37, 35, 38, 29, 18, 45,
        60, 49, 62, 55, 78, 96, 29, 22, 24, 13,
        14, 11, 11, 18, 12, 12, 30, 52, 52, 44,
        28, 28, 20, 56, 40, 31, 50, 40, 46, 42,
        29, 19, 36, 25, 22, 17, 19, 26, 30, 20,
        15, 21, 11, 8, 8, 19, 5, 8, 8, 11,
        11, 8, 3, 9, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6, 3,
        5, 4, 5, 6
    };
```

**Requirements**

- Space limit to 2-3GB max but time should be O(n^something) not
  (something^n).
- The bag must not be sorted and duplicate must not be    removed.
- The result should be the indices of the numbers in the    matching
  subset, not the numbers themselves (as we have duplicates).

**Dynamic Programming Attempt**

Here is the C# dynamic programming version adapted from an answer to a similar question here on stackoverflow.com:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Utilities
{
    public static class Combinations
    {
        private static Dictionary<int, bool> m_memo = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
        private static Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, int>> m_previous = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        static Combinations()
        {
            m_memo.Clear();
            m_previous.Clear();
            m_memo[0] = true;
            m_previous[0] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(-1, 0);

        }

        public static bool FindSubset(IList<int> set, int sum)
        {
            //m_memo.Clear();
            //m_previous.Clear();
            //m_memo[0] = true;
            //m_previous[0] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(-1, 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < set.Count; ++i)
            {
                int num = set[i];
                for (int s = sum; s >= num; --s)
                {
                    if (m_memo.ContainsKey(s - num) && m_memo[s - num] == true)
                    {
                        m_memo[s] = true;

                        if (!m_previous.ContainsKey(s))
                        {
                            m_previous[s] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(i, num);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return m_memo.ContainsKey(sum) && m_memo[sum];
        }
        public static IEnumerable<int> GetLastIndex(int sum)
        {
            while (m_previous[sum].Key != -1)
            {
                yield return m_previous[sum].Key;
                sum -= m_previous[sum].Value;
            }
        }

        public static void SubsetSumMain(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[]
        {
            7, 286, 200, 176, 120, 165, 206, 75, 129, 109,
            123, 111, 43, 52, 99, 128, 111, 110, 98, 135,
            112, 78, 118, 64, 77, 227, 93, 88, 69, 60,
            34, 30, 73, 54, 45, 83, 182, 88, 75, 85,
            54, 53, 89, 59, 37, 35, 38, 29, 18, 45,
            60, 49, 62, 55, 78, 96, 29, 22, 24, 13,
            14, 11, 11, 18, 12, 12, 30, 52, 52, 44,
            28, 28, 20, 56, 40, 31, 50, 40, 46, 42,
            29, 19, 36, 25, 22, 17, 19, 26, 30, 20,
            15, 21, 11, 8, 8, 19, 5, 8, 8, 11,
            11, 8, 3, 9, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6, 3,
            5, 4, 5, 6
        };

            int sum = 400;
            //int size = 4; // don't know to use in dynamic programming

            // call dynamic programming
            if (Numbers.FindSubset(numbers, sum))
            {
                foreach (int index in Numbers.GetLastIndex(sum))
                {
                    Console.Write((index + 1) + "." + numbers[index] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Recursive Programming Attempt**

and Here is the C# recursive programming version adapted from an answer to a similar question here on stackoverflow.com:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Utilities
{
    public static class Combinations
    {
        private static int s_count = 0;
        public static int CountSubsets(int[] numbers, int index, int current, int sum, int size, List<int> result)
        {
            if ((numbers.Length <= index) || (current > sum)) return 0;
            if (result == null) result = new List<int>();

            List<int> temp = new List<int>(result);
            if (current + numbers[index] == sum)
            {
                temp.Add(index);
                if ((size == 0) || (temp.Count == size))
                {
                    s_count++;
                }
            }
            else if (current + numbers[index] < sum)
            {
                temp.Add(index);
                CountSubsets(numbers, index + 1, current + numbers[index], sum, size, temp);
            }

            CountSubsets(numbers, index + 1, current, sum, size, result);
            return s_count;
        }

        private static List<List<int>> m_subsets = new List<List<int>>();
        public static List<List<int>> FindSubsets(int[] numbers, int index, int current, int sum, int size, List<int> result)
        {
            if ((numbers.Length <= index) || (current > sum)) return m_subsets;
            if (result == null) result = new List<int>();

            List<int> temp = new List<int>(result);
            if (current + numbers[index] == sum)
            {
                temp.Add(index);
                if ((size == 0) || (temp.Count == size))
                {
                    m_subsets.Add(temp);
                }
            }
            else if (current + numbers[index] < sum)
            {
                temp.Add(index);
                FindSubsets(numbers, index + 1, current + numbers[index], sum, size, temp);
            }

            FindSubsets(numbers, index + 1, current, sum, size, result);

            return m_subsets;
        }

        public static void SubsetSumMain(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[]
        {
            7, 286, 200, 176, 120, 165, 206, 75, 129, 109,
            123, 111, 43, 52, 99, 128, 111, 110, 98, 135,
            112, 78, 118, 64, 77, 227, 93, 88, 69, 60,
            34, 30, 73, 54, 45, 83, 182, 88, 75, 85,
            54, 53, 89, 59, 37, 35, 38, 29, 18, 45,
            60, 49, 62, 55, 78, 96, 29, 22, 24, 13,
            14, 11, 11, 18, 12, 12, 30, 52, 52, 44,
            28, 28, 20, 56, 40, 31, 50, 40, 46, 42,
            29, 19, 36, 25, 22, 17, 19, 26, 30, 20,
            15, 21, 11, 8, 8, 19, 5, 8, 8, 11,
            11, 8, 3, 9, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6, 3,
            5, 4, 5, 6
        };

            int sum = 17;
            int size = 2;

            // call backtracking recursive programming
            Console.WriteLine("CountSubsets");
            int count = Numbers.CountSubsets(numbers, 0, 0, sum, size, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Count = " + count);
            Console.WriteLine();

            // call backtracking recursive programming
            Console.WriteLine("FindSubsets");
            List<List<int>> subsets = Numbers.FindSubsets(numbers, 0, 0, sum, size, null);
            for (int i = 0; i < subsets.Count; i++)
            {
                if (subsets[i] != null)
                {
                    Console.Write((i + 1).ToString() + ":\t");
                    for (int j = 0; j < subsets[i].Count; j++)
                    {
                        int index = subsets[i][j];
                        Console.Write((index + 1) + "." + numbers[index] + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Count = " + subsets.Count);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to restrict the dynamic programming version to subsets of size k and if I can call it repeatedly so it returns different subsets on every call until there are no more matching subsets.

Also I am not sure where to initialize the memo of the DP algorithm. I did it in the static constructor which auto-runs when accessing any method. Is this the correct initialization place or does it need to be moved to inside the FindSunset() method [commented out]?

As for the recursive version, is it backtracking? and how can we speed it up. It works correctly and takes k and s into account but totally inefficient.

Let's make this thread the mother of all C# SubsetSum related questions!

Comment: Please don't just dump a wall of code on us and ask us to review it for you. We have [codereview.se] for that purpose.

Comment: If, and only if the code works as intended, may the question be on-topic for Code Review. This phrase: _"Please let me know how to restrict the dynamic programming version to subsets of size k"_ makes it sound like the desired behavior is not written yet.

Comment: There are two versions:

Comment: There are two versions: The backtracking is working correctly with restrictive k-size but inefficient. The dynamic programming version however doesn't take into account the desired k-size of subsets but worse still it only returns the first matching subsets it finds. I am hoping for an efficient solution. The wall of code would have saved me lots of time had I found it as is. Instead I had to collect it from multiple questions to make it work. Thank you for the head up for the Code Review service but my question still stands. Is DP able to get the Next subset repeatedly until all found? ThanQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer works on the principle of cutting off the number of combinations to check. But this can be improved significantly once you sort the array. The principle is similar, but since the solution is entirely different, I've decided to put it in a separate answer.

I was careful to use only .Net Framework 2.0 features. Might add a visual explanation later, but the comments should be enough.

```
class Puzzle
{
    private readonly int[] _tailSums;
    public readonly SubsetElement[] Elements;
    public readonly int N;

    public Puzzle(int[] numbers)
    {
        // Set N and make Elements array
        // (to remember the original index of each element)
        this.N = numbers.Length;
        this.Elements = new SubsetElement[this.N];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.N; i++)
        {
            this.Elements[i] = new SubsetElement(numbers[i], i);
        }

        // Sort Elements descendingly by their Number value
        Array.Sort(this.Elements, (a, b) => b.Number.CompareTo(a.Number));

        // Save tail-sums to allow immediate access by index
        // Allow immedate calculation by index = N, to sum 0
        this._tailSums = new int[this.N + 1];
        var sum = 0;

        for (var i = this.N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            this._tailSums[i] = sum += this.Elements[i].Number;
        }
    }

    public void Solve(int s, Action<SubsetElement[]> callback)
    {
        for (var k = 1; k <= this.N; k++)
            this.Solve(k, s, callback);
    }

    public void Solve(int k, int s, Action<SubsetElement[]> callback)
    {
        this.ScanSubsets(0, k, s, new List<SubsetElement>(), callback);
    }

    private void ScanSubsets(int startIndex, int k, int s,
                             List<SubsetElement> subset, Action<SubsetElement[]> cb)
    {
        // No more numbers to add, and current subset is guranteed to be valid
        if (k == 0)
        {
            // Callback with current subset
            cb(subset.ToArray());
            return;
        }

        // Sum the smallest k elements
        var minSubsetStartIndex = this.N - k;
        var minSum = this._tailSums[minSubssetStartIndex];

        // Smallest possible sum is greater than wanted sum,
        // so a valid subset cannot be found
        if (minSum > s)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Find largest number that satisfies the condition
        // that a valid subset can be found
        minSum -= this.Elements[minSubsetStartIndex].Number;

        // But remember the last index that satisfies the condition
        var minSubsetEndIndex = minSubsetStartIndex;

        while (minSubsetStartIndex > startIndex &&
               minSum + this.Elements[minSubsetStartIndex - 1].Number <= s)
        {
            minSubsetStartIndex--;
        }

        // Find the first number in the sorted sequence that is
        // the largest number we just found (in case of duplicates)
        while (minSubsetStartIndex > startIndex &&
               Elements[minSubsetStartIndex] == Elements[minSubsetStartIndex - 1])
        {
            minSubsetStartIndex--;
        }

        // [minSubsetStartIndex .. maxSubsetEndIndex] is the
        // full range we must check in recursion

        for (var subsetStartIndex = minSubsetStartIndex;
             subsetStartIndex <= minSubsetEndIndex;
             subsetStartIndex++)
        {
            // Find the largest possible sum, which is the sum of the
            // k first elements, starting at current subsetStartIndex
            var maxSum = this._tailSums[subsetStartIndex] -
                         this._tailSums[subsetStartIndex + k];

            // The largest possible sum is less than the wanted sum,
            // so a valid subset cannot be found
            if (maxSum < s)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Add current number to the subset
            var x = this.Elements[subsetStartIndex];
            subset.Add(x);

            // Recurse through the sub-problem to the right
            this.ScanSubsets(subsetStartIndex + 1, k - 1, s - x.Number, subset, cb);

            // Remove current number and continue loop
            subset.RemoveAt(subset.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    public sealed class SubsetElement
    {
        public readonly int Number;
        public readonly int Index;

        public SubsetElement(int number, int index)
        {
            this.Number = number;
            this.Index = index;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}({1})", this.Number, this.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage and performance testing:**

```
private static void Main()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var puzzle = new Puzzle(new[]
        {
            7, 286, 200, 176, 120, 165, 206, 75, 129, 109,
            123, 111, 43, 52, 99, 128, 111, 110, 98, 135,
            112, 78, 118, 64, 77, 227, 93, 88, 69, 60,
            34, 30, 73, 54, 45, 83, 182, 88, 75, 85,
            54, 53, 89, 59, 37, 35, 38, 29, 18, 45,
            60, 49, 62, 55, 78, 96, 29, 22, 24, 13,
            14, 11, 11, 18, 12, 12, 30, 52, 52, 44,
            28, 28, 20, 56, 40, 31, 50, 40, 46, 42,
            29, 19, 36, 25, 22, 17, 19, 26, 30, 20,
            15, 21, 11, 8, 8, 19, 5, 8, 8, 11,
            11, 8, 3, 9, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6, 3,
            5, 4, 5, 6
        });

    puzzle.Solve(2, 17, PuzzleOnSubsetFound);

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Subsets found: " + _subsetsCount);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}

private static int _subsetsCount;

private static void PuzzleOnSubsetFound(Puzzle.SubsetElement[] subset)
{
    _subsetsCount++;
    return; // Skip prints when speed-testing

    foreach (var el in subset)
    {
        Console.Write(el.ToString());
        Console.Write("  ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output:**

Each line is a found subset, numbers in () are the original index of the number used in the subset

> 14(60)  3(107)
>   14(60)  3(109)
>   14(60)  3(102)
>   13(59)  4(105)
>   13(59)  4(111)
>   12(64)  5(96)
>   12(64)  5(104)
>   12(64)  5(112)
>   12(64)  5(110)
>   12(65)  5(96)
>   12(65)  5(104)
>   12(65)  5(112)
>   12(65)  5(110)
>   11(100)  6(108)
>   11(100)  6(113)
>   11(61)  6(108)
>   11(61)  6(113)
>   11(92)  6(108)
>   11(92)  6(113)
>   11(62)  6(108)
>   11(62)  6(113)
>   11(99)  6(108)
>   11(99)  6(113)
>   9(103)  8(93)
>   9(103)  8(94)
>   9(103)  8(97)
>   9(103)  8(98)
>   9(103)  8(101)
>   Subsets found: 28
>   00:00:00.0017020 (measured when no printing is performed)

---

The higher `k` is, the more cutoffs can be made. This is when you'll see the major performance difference. Your current code (the recursive version) also performs significantly slower when `s` is goes higher.

> With `k=5`, `s=60`
>   Your current code: found 45070 subsets in **2.8602923** seconds
>   My code: found 45070 subsets in **0.0116727** seconds
>   That is **99.6%** speed improvement

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you so much. Would you please deal with the case where k=0 to mean any subset size and can you please confirm that in the worst case scenario, this is still runs in O(2^n)?

Comment: You can run a loop for all k's if you want. It runs in better than O(2^n), I believe it is O(n^k) or something.

Comment: I think it runs in O(2^k) not O(2^n) which is a huge improvement.

Comment: Maybe O(k^k) instead of O(n^n)? This stuff always confuses me. I just benchmark.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it's O(n^k) as I thought before. In each level of recursion I'm looping through a part of the set. Throughout all levels in any specific recursion branch, the number of elements I scanned (or skipped, but cutoffs don't really change the upper bound) all add of to O(n). And there are k levels of recursion, so O(n^k) sounds generally correct. I don't think any of the attempted implementations was ever O(2^n).

Comment: Thank you very much and for those who may wonder what is so specific about these 114 numbers, please see how they hold so many amazing patterns including the golden ratio correct to 3 decimal digits: http://heliwave.com/114.txt and http://piephi.com

Comment: I'd appreciate a thank-you if this goes publish ;p Can further be improved by precalculating an array of `minSums`.

Comment: Can you please add the option for when k=0; then the method returns all matching subsets regardless of size. Thank you.

Comment: What edit? I can't see any new edit and I have also added check for when k > n as it currently goes index out of bound.

Comment: There is an overload `void Solve(int s, Action<SubsetElement[]> callback)` that runs through `k` values

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for changes to the algorithm itself to reduce the checking against k, rather than recall the method k times. This is good enough but if you can think of new brilliant ideas then add then to the code  for the benefit of all readers.

Comment: @AliAdams The only way I can think of improving this at the moment is precalculating the tail-sums of the sorted elements to allow immediate access to sum values by index. See the edit I've added

Comment: I corrected the new code in constructor, add at the end:

    this._tailSums = new int[this.N + 1];
    for (var i = this.N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        this._tailSums[i] = this._tailSums[i + 1] +
                     this.Elements[i].Number;

Comment: //int size = 7;
            //int sum = 313;
            //Subsets1 found: 122131009
            //00:00:33.5053340
            //Subsets2 found: 122131009
            //00:00:30.2087779

            //int size = 9;
            //int sum = 911;
            //Subsets1 found: 766732123
            //00:04:20.1139367
            //Subsets2 found: 766732123
            //00:04:08.2344704

Comment: I'll edit the code. You need to think of the tail array as if it is of size `N`, and then add a `0` at the end just to save an `if` from the `Solve` method.

Comment: Can you please add an option to find all **ordered** subsets? So the same subset of elements but with different element order constitutes a new answer. Example, there are 1,560,780 ways of choosing 7 elements from a set of 29 elements, but if order is important then that number is multiplied by 7! and becomes 7,866,331,200. Latest code can be downloaded from [link](http://qurancode.com) See the Subsets.cs in the Utilities folder and its usage in the WordGenerator project. Thank you. God >

Comment: @AliAdams Just take every subset you get from this algorithm and go through its permutations to get all uniquely ordered subsets

Comment: I know that but I was thinking maybe there is an inline fix within the algorithm itself to make it in one step and perhaps faster too. Please see http://heliwave.com/506.txt

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions, but nobody showed how to use dynamic programming to find the answer.

The key is to use dynamic programming to build up a data structure from which all solutions can later be found.

In addition to the requested function, I collected information about how many solutions there are, and wrote `FindSolution(node, position)` to return the solution at position `position` starting with `node` without calculating the rest.  If you want all of them, using that function would be inefficient.  But, for example, with this function it is doable to calculate the billionth way to express 10000 as a sum of 20 primes.  That would not be feasible with the other approaches given.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SubsetSum
{
    public class SolutionNode<T>
    {
        // The index we found the value at
        public int Index {get; set;}
        // The value we add for this solution
        public T Value {get; set;}
        // How many solutions we have found.
        public int Count {get; set;}
        // The rest of this solution.
        public SolutionNode<T> Tail {get; set;}
        // The next solution.
        public SolutionNode<T> Next {get; set;}
    }

    // This uses dynamic programming to create a summary of all solutions.
    public static SolutionNode<int> FindSolution(int[] numbers, int target, int subsetSize)
    {
        // By how many are in our list, by what they sum to, what SolutionNode<int> has our answer?
        List<Dictionary<int, SolutionNode<int>>> solutionOf = new List<Dictionary<int, SolutionNode<int>>>();

        // Initialize empty solutions.
        for (int i = 0; i <= subsetSize; i++)
        {
            solutionOf.Add(new Dictionary<int, SolutionNode<int>>());
        }

        // We discover from the last number in the list forward.
        // So discovering from the last index forward makes them ordered.
        for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; -1 < i; i--)
        {
            int number = numbers[i];
            // Descending here so we don't touch solutionOf[j-1] until after we have solutionOf[j] updated.
            for (int j = subsetSize; 0 < j; j--)
            {
                // All previously found sums with j entries
                Dictionary<int, SolutionNode<int>> after = solutionOf[j];
                // All previously found sums with j-1 entries
                Dictionary<int, SolutionNode<int>> before = solutionOf[j-1];
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SolutionNode<int>> pair in before)
                {
                    SolutionNode<int> newSolution = new SolutionNode<int>();
                    int newSum = pair.Key + number;
                    newSolution.Index = i;
                    newSolution.Value = number;
                    newSolution.Count = pair.Value.Count;
                    newSolution.Tail = pair.Value;
                    if (after.ContainsKey(newSum))
                    {
                        newSolution.Next = after[newSum];
                        newSolution.Count = pair.Value.Count + after[newSum].Count;
                    }
                    after[newSum] = newSolution;
                }

                // And special case empty set.
                if (1 == j)
                {
                    SolutionNode<int> newSolution = new SolutionNode<int>();
                    newSolution.Index = i;
                    newSolution.Value = number;
                    newSolution.Count = 1;
                    if (after.ContainsKey(number))
                    {
                        newSolution.Next = after[number];
                        newSolution.Count = after[number].Count;
                    }
                    after[number] = newSolution;
                }
            }
        }

        // Return what we found.
        try
        {
            return solutionOf[subsetSize][target];
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("No solutions found");
        }
    }

    // The function we were asked for.
    public static IEnumerable<List<int>> ListSolutions (SolutionNode<int> node)
    {
        List<int> solution = new List<int>();
        List<SolutionNode<int>> solutionPath = new List<SolutionNode<int>>();

        // Initialize with starting information.
        solution.Add(0); // This will be removed when we get node
        solutionPath.Add(node); // This will be our start.

        while (0 < solutionPath.Count)
        {
            // Erase the tail of our previous solution
            solution.RemoveAt(solution.Count - 1);
            // Pick up our next.
            SolutionNode<int> current = solutionPath[solutionPath.Count - 1];
            solutionPath.RemoveAt(solutionPath.Count - 1);
            while (current != null)
            {
                solution.Add(current.Index);
                solutionPath.Add(current.Next);
                if (current.Tail == null)
                {
                    yield return solution;
                }
                current = current.Tail;
            }
        }
    }

    // And for fun, a function that dynamic programming makes easy - return any one of them!
    public static List<int> FindSolution(SolutionNode<int> node, int position)
    {
        // Switch to counting from the end.
        position = node.Count - position - 1;
        List<int> solution = new List<int>();
        while (node != null)
        {
            while (node.Next != null && position < node.Next.Count)
            {
                node = node.Next;
            }
            solution.Add(node.Index);
            node = node.Tail;
        }
        return solution;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SolutionNode<int> solution = FindSolution(
            new[]{
                7, 286, 200, 176, 120, 165, 206, 75, 129, 109,
            123, 111, 43, 52, 99, 128, 111, 110, 98, 135,
            112, 78, 118, 64, 77, 227, 93, 88, 69, 60,
            34, 30, 73, 54, 45, 83, 182, 88, 75, 85,
            54, 53, 89, 59, 37, 35, 38, 29, 18, 45,
            60, 49, 62, 55, 78, 96, 29, 22, 24, 13,
            14, 11, 11, 18, 12, 12, 30, 52, 52, 44,
            28, 28, 20, 56, 40, 31, 50, 40, 46, 42,
            29, 19, 36, 25, 22, 17, 19, 26, 30, 20,
            15, 21, 11, 8, 8, 19, 5, 8, 8, 11,
            11, 8, 3, 9, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6, 3,
            5, 4, 5, 6}
            , 400, 4);
        IEnumerable<List<int>> listing = ListSolutions(solution);
        foreach (List<int> sum in listing)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("solution {0}", string.Join(", ", sum.ToArray()));
        }
    }
}
```

Incidentally this is my first time trying to write C#.  It was...painfully verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Simply search for all combinations of size K, and check each if it satisfies the condition.

The fastest algorithm for `k` combinations, suiting your case, would be:

```
for (var i1 = 0; i1 <= n; i1++)
{
    for (var i2 = i1 + 1; i2 <= n; i2++)
    {
        for (var i3 = i2 + 1; i3 <= n; i3++)
        {
            ...

            for (var ik = iOneBeforeK + 1; ik <= n; ik++)
            {
                if (arr[i1] + arr[i2] + ... + arr[ik] == sum)
                {
                    // this is a valid subset
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you are talking about numbers and summing them up, meaning you could make cutoffs with a smarter algorithm.

Since all numbers are positive, you know that if a single number is big enough, you cannot add to it any more positive numbers and have it sum up to `s`. Given `s=6` and `k=4`, the highest number to include in the search is `s-k+1=3`. `3+1+1+1` is `k` numbers, `1` being your lowest possible number, sums up to `6`. Any number above 3 couldn't have 3 other positives added to it, and have the sum <= 6.

But wait, your minimum possible value isn't `1`, it is `3`. That's even better. So assume `k=10`, `n=60`, `min=3`. The "highest number scenario" is `x+min(k-1)=n` -> `x=60-3*9=33`. So the highest number to even consider would be `33`.

This cuts the amount of relevant numbers in the array to consider, hence it cuts the amount of combinations to look for.

But it gets even better. Assume `k=10`, `n=60`, `min=3`. The first number in the array happens to be `20`, so it is relevant and should be checked. Lets find the relevant subsets that include that 20:
A new "puzzle" appears! `k=10-1`, `n=60-20`, `min=3`. You can now cutoff many numbers from the subpuzzle, and again and again which each step further in.

This can be improved even further by calculating the average of the `k-1` lowest numbers in the subpuzzle and use that as `min`.

It is possible to improve this even further by precalculating the `k` lowest numbers average in subpuzzle `[0..n]`, and `k-1` lowest numbers average in subpuzzle `[1..n]`, and `k-2` lowest numbers average in subpuzzle `[2..n]` and so on, and use them instead of recalculating same stuff again and again within each subpuzzle assessment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot change the bag's size from 114 as that would produce results correct only for the cut-down bag but are incorrect for the original 114-element bag which is what I need. And that k-nested loops is fixed at compile time whereas k is a run-time parameter, plus there must be a more efficient way than that. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Ali This answer is a work in progress. Please check the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use code below. Sorry, i had not time to optimise code. You can compare all methods that you have, and and make conclusion which is faster, don't forgot to share results.

C# (you can try to rid from List may be it will give you performance improvement:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<int>> findSubsetsWithLengthKAndSumS2(Tuple<int, int> ks, List<int> set, List<int> subSet, List<int> subSetIndex)
    {
        if (ks.Item1 == 0 && ks.Item2 == 0)
        {
            var res = new List<List<int>>();
            res.Add(subSetIndex);
            return res;
        }
        else if (ks.Item1 > 0 && ks.Item2 > 0)
        {
            var res = set.Select((x, i) =>
            {
                var newSubset = subSet.Select(y => y).ToList();
                newSubset.Add(x);

                var newSubsetIndex = subSetIndex.Select(y => y).ToList();
                newSubsetIndex.Add(i);

                var newSet = set.Skip(i).ToList();
                return findSubsetsWithLengthKAndSumS2(Tuple.Create(ks.Item1 - 1, ks.Item2 - x), newSet, newSubset, newSubsetIndex).ToList();
            }
            ).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
            return res;
        }
        else
            return new List<List<int>>();
    }
...
            var res = findSubsetsWithLengthKAndSumS2(Tuple.Create(2, 293), numbers.ToList(), new List<int>(), new List<int>());
```

F# (I added it Just for fun =), it is not optimized too, i beleive the slowest place in code is 'skip' ):

```
let skip (list:List<int>) index = 
    list |> List.mapi (fun i x -> if i > index then Some(x) else None) |> List.filter (fun x -> x.IsSome) |> List.map (fun  x -> x.Value)

let rec findSubsetsWithLengthKAndSumS (ks:int*int) (set:list<int>) (subSet:list<int>) =
    [
        match ks with
        |0,0 ->   yield subSet 
        | x,y when x > 0 && y > 0 -> yield! set |> List.mapi (fun i x-> findSubsetsWithLengthKAndSumS ((fst ks)-1,(snd ks)-x)   (skip set i ) (x::subSet)) |> Seq.concat
        | _,_-> yield []
    ]
...
    let res = Subsets.findSubsetsWithLengthKAndSumS (2,293)  numbers [] |> List.filter (fun x-> x.Length >0)
```

I beleive this Iterative version would be faster than others in many times. It uses **.net 2.0**:

```
    public delegate IEnumerable< IEnumerable< int > > findSubset();

    public delegate bool findSubsetsIterativeFilter( int[] sourceSet, int[] indiciesToSum, int expected );

    public static bool Summ( int[] sourceSet, int[] indicies, int expected )
    {
        var sum = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < indicies.Length; i++ )
            sum += sourceSet[ indicies[ i ] ];
        return sum == expected;
    }

    public static IEnumerable< IEnumerable< int > > findSubsetsIterative( int k, int[] sourceSet, findSubsetsIterativeFilter specialCondition, int expected )
    {
        var a = new int[ k ];
        for( int i = 0; i < k; i++ )
            a[ i ] = i; 

        var p = k - 1;
        while( p >= 0 )
        {
            if( specialCondition( sourceSet, a, expected ) )
                yield return ( int[] )a.Clone();
            p = ( a[ k - 1 ] == sourceSet.Length - 1 ) ? p - 1 : k - 1;
            if( p >= 0 )
                for( int i = k - 1; i >= p; i-- )
                    a[ i ] = a[ p ] + i - p + 1;
        }
    }
    ...
       findSubsetsIterative( 2, a, Summ, 293 );
```

I had measured my code and Yorye's and here is what i get. My code is faster in 4-10x. Did you used 'findSubsetsIterative' from my answer in your experiments?

> findSubsetsIterative( 4, GenerateSOurceData(1), Summ, 400 )  Elapsed:
>   00:00:00.0012113  puzzle.Solve(4, 400, PuzzleOnSubsetFound)  Elapsed:
>   00:00:00.0046170
>
> findSubsetsIterative( 5, GenerateSOurceData(1), Summ, 60 )  Elapsed:
>   00:00:00.0012960  puzzle.Solve(5, 60, PuzzleOnSubsetFound)  Elapsed:
>   00:00:00.0108568
>
> Here i increased incoming array in 5x (just copied array 5 times into new big array):
>   findSubsetsIterative( 5, GenerateSOurceData(5), Summ, 60 )
>   Elapsed: 00:00:00.0013067
>   puzzle.Solve(5, 60, PuzzleOnSubsetFound)
>   Elapsed: 00:00:21.3520840

Comment: I am not allowed to use Linq I am afraid. Must stick to .NET 2.0 preferable with [] arrays only, but List<int> is also acceptable. Thank you for the code and I hope others might find it useful too.

Comment: Ok, i had added iterative version which can be run on .net 2.0 and this method is faster then others in hundreds of times. This is because it has low level data structures implementation and has low time complicity. Is it suitable for you?

Comment: Thank very much for your efforts. I will test it and report back.

Comment: OK I have benchmarked both solutions (your and Yorye's) for
int k = 4;
int s = 400;

            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> result = findSubsetsIterative(k, s, array, Sum);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (IEnumerable<int> value in result)
            {
                count++;
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Subsets found: " + count);

Subsets found: 5456
00:00:00.5442583

Yorye's solution took:
Subsets found: 5456
00:00:00.0108487

So 5442583/108487 ~= 50 times faster

Comment: @AliAdams, it is strange for me, on my old notebook my method took 00:00:00:001. What environment did you used? Can you make sure that both methods were tested in the same environment and without printing info and other i/o?

Comment: @AliAdams I have benchmarked both solutions, results you can found above, my code is faster 10 times.

Comment: your return collection has no Count and therefore needs further processing to get the count of found subsets.

Comment: IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> result = findSubsetsIterative(k, s, array, Sum);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (IEnumerable<int> value in result)
            {
                count++;
            }

Comment: REPORT: k=7 s=313 Yorye's code took 30s yours took 1hr6min ------------ //Subsets2 found: 122131009 at 00:00:30.2087779  versus lazy-loading IEnumerable Subsets found: 854917063 at 01:06:22.2569331 AND your produces exactly k times more sets!!! Why?

Comment: May be there is an error in one of algorythms? Also, i agreed that dynamic progrmming usually provides faster solutions ( but not always, i think ). I will test both solutions on k=7 and s=313 and will try to answer soon.

Comment: Thank you and if you like to see how I am using it, feel free to experiment with this open source tool: http://quranlab.codeplex.com as I have overloaded the scan method for faster counting-only feature without calling back a delegate when finding a match.

Comment: I tested, both methods works for me and gives the same result  122 131 009. I think there are errors in your implementation

Comment: I am really interested in how fast it compares for counting-only and for actual resultant subsets. Please check the time AFTER you try to access the results, as it uses lazy-loading and anything before accessing the result gives false time? Thank you. Please update me.

Answer (score 0):

it can be solved by a similar solution as the knapsack problem

dp[i][j][k]=number of k-size subsets with sum equal to j using first "i" elements

dp[i][j][k]=dp[i-1][j][k] + dp[i-1][j-a[i]][k-1]

is the update of the dp (using the ith element or not using it)

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) dp[i][0][0]=1;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=w;j++){
        for(int k=1;k<=i;k++){
            dp[i][j][k]=dp[i-1][j][k] ;
            if(j>=a[i-1]){
                dp[i][j][k]+=dp[i-1][j-a[i-1]][k-1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code in your answer to make give it clarity. See [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do this.